# When Using OptaPlanner WebExample on our Server it giving internal server error

Tags: java, rest, jsp, jboss, optaplanner

This response is coming on when we click on solve the planning problem button on my server.

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Internal Server Error</body></html>
```

But when I am doing on localhost it gives response proper.

Comment: Please add the exact error to your question, and show us a log if there is one. Also if you can add any more specific info you might have a higher chance of getting an answer.

Comment: What server are you using to deploy the web example? Go look at the log file from your server, it should contain stack trace about the internal server error, then please provide that data in here, so we could help you better.